# Compositions of functions: How to assign functions $f(x), g(x)$ so that $f(g(x))=\tan(x^3) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, function-and-relation-composition

How can we define $\tan(x^3)$ with $f(g(x))$ composite function. I tried to do it this way but it didn't work.

$$g(x)=\sin(x)/\cos(x)$$

$$f(x)=x^3$$

---

*Editor's note: he is trying to pick an appropriate $f$ and $g$ so that $f(g(x))$ is the desired outcome.  $f$ and $g$ are not fixed*

Comment: Essentially the same as [your previous post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971369/stuck-with-a-problem-about-functions).  Be careful of whether we are talking about $\tan(x^3)$ or if we are talking about $(\tan(x))^3$.  There is no reason to rewrite $\tan$ as $\frac{\sin}{\cos}$ in this case either.  With $f(x)=x^3$ and $g(x)=\tan(x)$, which is $\tan(x^3)$?  Was that $f(g(x))$ or was that $g(f(x))$?

Comment: yes it is f(g(x))

Comment: No.  Given what you wrote it is in fact $g(f(x))$.  One has $f(g(x))$ with the functions you gave will be $(\tan(x))^3$ which is not the desired outcome.  What can you do then to change $f$ and $g$ in order to get the desired outcome?

Comment: If instead we made $f(x) = \tan x$ and $g(x) = x^3$, ***then*** we have $$\tan(x^3) = f(g(x))$$

Answer (score 2):

You had the right choice of which functions to use, but you named them incorrectly.  In other words,

We want $$\color{green}{f}(\color{blue}{g(x)}) = \color{green}{\tan}(\color{blue}{x^3})$$

So let's name $\color{blue}{g(x) = x^3}$, and so $\color{green}{f(x) = \tan(x)}$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ , $g(x)=x^3$ , hence $\tan(x^3)=\frac{\sin(x^3)}{\cos(x^3)}$ , hence $\tan(x^3)=f(g(x))$